# (R) All data going into 1st row of new column of data frame

Tags: matrix

I've got a data frame, 1447 obs of 165 variables, and am looking to add columns by processing existing ones. I've got:

```
resvar <- 111  
# column number of response variable (e.g. CPUE) in "samples" (the data frame)
```

and am looking to log1p that column, 111, row by row, to a new column, called "grv" at the end of samples:

```
samples$grv <- log1p(samples[resvar])
```

But it puts the output into column grv, row 1, as ``c(item1,item2,...item1447)`

```
class(log1p(samples[resvar])) = data.frame
```

Does anyone know what's going on & why it's not working?
If I do

```
dummy <- log1p(samples[resvar])
```

`dummy` is a data.frame with row name the same as the row name from resvar, column 111's row name. Is this the problem?

Comment: `samples$grv <- log1p(samples[,resvar])` or `samples$grv <- log1p(samples[[resva]])`.

Answer (score 0):

`samples$grv <- log1p(samples[,resvar])` or `samples$grv <- log1p(samples[[resva]])`

Comment: @ConjugatePrior I'll thank you when it gets accepted.